# $.ajax with GET

Tags: jquery, ajax

when we call $.ajax with GET method

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "test.js",
  data: "id="+id
});
```

how to pass data to request file

is above given code is correct for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option to pass data as part of the request is called `data`, not `dataType`.

Have a read of the different options you can pass at: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You can either craft the query/data string yourself, or let jQuery do it by just passing an object.

so your ajax signature should look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "test.js",
  data: "id="+id
});
```

or

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "test.js",
  data: {
      id: id
  }
});
```

should both work

Answer (score 1):

Your one is correct (but `data`, not `dataType`), as well as

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "test.js",
  data: {
      id: id
  }
});
```

is correct too

Comment: it was mistake in my post ...I also use data

Comment: @Matt: yep, realized that few moments after :-S

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "test.js",
  data: "id="+id,   //not dataType  
  success: function(response) {
     //do osmething with response
  }
});
```